# Change div background acording to the selected category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm coding a graphic menu that consist in five divs with a background each. On mouseover the background changes and the child div disappears. On click, each one works like a link to the correspondent category. I want to apply some changes to the clicked div, so I was wonder if there is some function in wordpress to get the selected category. So I can check for It and in function of wich category is selected apply the changes to the correspondent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your theme, you might be able to extract this information from the `body` tag or post wrapper div, which gets dynamically populated with a ton of juicy information in the form of classes.

If your theme doesn't have this, you could try The Mother Of All WordPress Body Tags in your theme:

```
<body
id="
    <?php
    $post_parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
    $parentSlug = $post_parent->post_name;
    if (is_category()) { echo "CategoryPage"; }
    elseif (is_search()) { echo "SearchResults"; }
    elseif (is_tag()) { echo "Tag"; }
    else { echo $parentSlug; }
    ?>"
class="
    <?php
    if (is_category()) { echo 'category'; }
    elseif (is_search()) { echo 'search'; }
    elseif (is_tag()) { echo "tag"; }
    elseif (is_home()) { echo "home"; }
    elseif (is_404()) { echo "page404"; }
    else { echo $post->post_name; }
    ?>">
```

Reference: http://www.mimoymima.com/2010/03/lab/wordpress-body-tag/